# How can client implement a remote database on a shiny app interface?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create and deploy a shiny app with the final goal to create Rmarkdown reports on products available in a shop (it is an simplified example). In that software, the shop manager should be able to :

1. Create report on existing products
2. Add new items to this app and reports to adapt its shop to new taste of the clients.

[image]

Here is an example of the app: https://charlottesirot1985.shinyapps.io/EssaiApp/

To do so, I created a database of products (like an inventory). At the beginning the database is very simple but the shop manager will be able to implement this database by adding the new products through the shiny interface.

For some reasons that would be too long to explain here, I would like this app to be deployed and the database would then be a remote database that can be changed by the shiny users.
I am not sure that it is possible to update remote database from this kind of shiny app.
I already checked those: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html
and https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/client-data.html but I cannot find the solution (I think I miss the good keywords).

Do you have an idea ? Do you have some literature for me to read ? Tutorial or even correct keywords ? If it is not possible, I will try to think about another solution.

Thanks in advance,

Charlotte

Comment: How to update a database? SQL's `INSERT` and `UPDATE` commands are made for this. As for how to deploy a database with your app, I think it's a big vague. Are you using SQLite, DuckDB, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MariaDB, MySQL, or something else? Do you mean "database" in that method, or do you mean a local `data.frame` or collection of them? FYI, asking general server questions is more appropriate at https://serverfault.com or https://superuser.com, and are off-topic for SO, and asking for advice on which is best will likely be off-topic on all three.

Comment: Thanks R2evans ! This was exactly my question. I have so far no experience in SQL so I was wondering if some SQL functions were already existing in R. I will try to investigate more about that topic and may post my answer if it is ok (?)

Comment: Links to consider: https://db.rstudio.com/, https://dbi.r-dbi.org/, then one of https://rsqlite.r-dbi.org/ or https://duckdb.org/. This will allow you to set up a "DBMS" in a single file that can be exported to shinyapps.io, and queried/updated live by the app. While concurrent reads scales well, the two file-based databases do not scale well to many concurrent read/write operations. If that doesn't work, you need to hire a DBA and/or software architect (and research where to deploy a "full" DBMS, not on shinyapps.io).

Comment: Both SQLite and DuckDB use single-file "database" files that support multiple tables, indices, etc, in most ways identical to a full-featured server-based database management system (DBMS). In a way, they're similar to MS Access files (though these two don't self-corrupt like Access does). No server process required. No user-authentication. It's just a file that supports SQL on its contents. SQLite is a fairly simplified SQL implementation, whereas DuckDB models after PostgreSQL. The latter alleges to be faster at most things. SQLite is used by most web browsers and most smartphones.